# LTspice MOSFET stops charging capacitor past Vt

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, buck-boost

I'm building a buck-boost converter that transfers C1's charge to C2. In the schematic shown below, C1's initial charge is 4V. When I use switches instead of MOSFETs in the circuit, everything works smoothly and C2's final voltage is somewhere around 3.5V (losses due to parasitics).

However, when I replace those switches with MOSFETs, C2's voltage starts to taper off around the threshold voltage of that MOSFET. In this scenario, the Vt is 0.843V, which is where C2 caps out around. What am I missing here? I initially thought it was turning off since the voltage at the source node is rising over time, but even if I drive the MOSFET with 15V at the gate (Vgs >> Vt), the results don't change. That also rules out the MOSFET dipping into saturation mode, since Vds << Vgs - Vt as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are M1 and M2 four terminal MOSFETs with bulk connection, or why is there a ground connection?

Comment: @winny OP probably had a switch and then replaced it with a MOS.

Comment: It looks like you modelled your switches with positive hysteresis (`vh>0`), which means they will abruptly switch between ON and OFF states. The MOS doesn't behave like that. Given your command voltage, try setting the switches to have `vt=2.5 vh=-1`, for example, to attempt a mimic of a MOS. You could also add some strategic capacitors in there (RC lowpass for the input, Cgd, Cds), or even an anti-parallel diode with proper leakage, and the results may change.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Oh! That makes sense.

Comment: On a second look, I see you added `vhigh` and `vlow` to the Schmitt triggers, but have you done that to the `srflop`, too? (the previous comment is still valid)

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Yes! Sorry, I forgot to make the parameters visible on the srflop as well. After staring at the circuit for a while, I managed to solve the issue. I was looking at -V(uc2) the entire time because the polarity of C2 is flipped, but the source node of M2 is actually decreasing (getting more negative) over time. So once the source node hit -Vt, and if I was biasing the gate of M2 at 0V when I wanted it to turn off, it was still turning on. I fixed the issue by biasing the gate with a negative voltage whenever I wanted it to turn off and stay off. Thanks for taking a look!